# Exclude "featured" entries from a "recent" entries {% for %} loop

Tags: entries-field

Here's my current setup:

**Blog (Channel)** - All of my blog posts will go here

**Blog Landing (Single)** - This section only has one field - a *Featured Articles* Entries field that lets me select 3 entries from the "Blog" channel.

Basically what I want to do on the Blog Landing section is have a dedicated area for the 3 Featured articles (ones that I will choose from that *Featured Articles* entries field), but then display the next 5 most recent articles that have **not** been selected as a Featured article in a different area.

I've successfully outputted my Featured Articles with this code:

```
{% set featured = entry.featuredArticles %}
  {% for entry in featured %}
    {{ entry.title }}
  {% endfor %}
```

And I can get my 5 most recent with this code:

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('blog') %}
  {% for entry in allEntries.limit(5) %}
   {{ entry.title }}
  {% endfor %}
```

I can't figure out how to exclude the entries from the *Featured Articles* area from the output of the *Recent Articles* area.

So say I have 10 entries in my Blog channel, (Post 1 is most recent, Post 2 is second most recent, and so on), and I've selected Posts 2, 4, and 5 as my "Featured" articles, how do I get it so that the 5 "Recent" articles display Posts 1, 3, 6, 7, and 8 instead of Posts 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5?

Comment: Hi Tyler, I don't have a direct answer, but check out [this thread](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9421/get-entries-thats-not-already-listed) I think it is almost exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could do is get the ids of the featured element, and exclude those from the second craft.entries call. Something like this:

```
{# Get the ids of the featured items you got above #}
{% set featuredIds = featured.ids() %}

{# Get entries in section 'blog' which don't have an id in featuredIds #}
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('blog').id('and, not ' ~ featuredIds | join(', not ')) %}

{# Loop and output #}
{% for entry in allEntries.limit(5) %}
  {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

The use of the join filter may seem a bit cryptic. But, when excluding one id from a list of entries, you'd do `.id('not 3')`. When excluding more than one, you need to specify the conditional first (the `and` part) and then a comma separated list of `not (id)`. So the join basically creates a string like `.id('and, not 3, not 4, not 5')`, if the ids of the featured articles where 3, 4 and 5.

Edit: added necessary space to `join(', not ')`

Answer (score 2):

```
{# set featured entries by finding their IDs #}    
{% set featuredEntries = entry.featuredArticles.ids() %}

{# set all entries by finding their IDs #}
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('blog').ids() %}

{# filter out the feature entries from the regular entries #}
{% set filteredEntries = allEntries|without(featuredEntries)

{# loop through blog entries, excluding featured entries #}
{% for entry in craft.entries.id(filteredEntries) %}
  {{ entry.title }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

The key here is using Craft's built-in [`|without`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/filters#without) filter to remove feature IDs from the regular IDs.

Comment: I like how approachable this seems and I think it works well to answer Tyler's scenario given the relatively low number of "Featured" entries. André's answer below, while a little tougher to understand for those new to Twig, would be better for heavier lifting (more entries).

Comment: That solution is about 50% less efficient. Not to mention the can of worms you open if you have more than 100 blog entries and want some kind of pagination.