# Omit Featured Entry from loop of entries with additional omissions

Tags: entries-field, id

I have a homepage single section has a field for entries (only 1 can be selected).
This field is called featuredEntry.

In my homepage template (index.html) I set a variable `{% set featured = entry.featuredEntry %}` for the field
I then loop thru that to pull in that entries content `{% for mainEntry in featured %}`

I have a listing of entries below it that pull from the same News channel as the featured entry above.
I don't want the featured entry to show in that list.

I followed the answer here ([Exclude "featured" entries from a "recent" entries {% for %} loop](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13821/exclude-featured-entries-from-a-recent-entries-for-loop)) with slight changes to try and omit that entry.

However, setting a variable `{% set featuredIds = featured.ids() %}` for the above featured entry doesn't seem to work.

I am omitting additional entries that are marked with a certain tag as explained here:
[List entries without specific tag](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/19428/list-entries-without-specific-tag)

What am I missing here or what is wrong for my code to not pull in that id of the featured entry?

```
{% set featuredIds = featured.ids() %}

{% set mainTag = craft.tags.search('All-Stars').first() %}
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('news') %}
{% set taggedEntries = craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo(mainTag).ids %}

{% set omitIds = 'and, not ' ~ taggedEntries|join(', not ') ~ allEntries|join(', not featuredIds') %}
{% set untaggedEntries = craft.entries.section('news').id(omitIds) %}

{% for feedItems in untaggedEntries.limit(5) %}
```

In that code above in the omitIds variable, if I do this:
`{% set omitIds = 'and, not ' ~ taggedEntries|join(', not ') ~ allEntries|join(', not SPECIFIC ID') %}`

It works.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My variable wasn't outputting the id and it wasn't being pulled into my omitIds variable

```
{% set featuredIds = entry.featuredEntry.first.id %}

{% set omitIds = 'and, not ' ~ taggedEntries|join(', not ') ~ allEntries|join(', not ' ~ featuredIds) %}
```

Adding `.first.id` to my `entry.featuredEntry` outputs the correct id.
Then removed `featuredIds` from the `', not '` in omitIds and added `~ featuredIds` pulls in the correct id and omits it from the list.

Feel free to edit as I'm sure I'm not explaining this correctly.